# Mongodb update on the mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

The following syntax tries to change the value of the `userId` property in the collection, but it is giving the following error, not sure how to fix it.

```
db.safetyHistoryCol.update({userId:'iu8fjfuyjd0jjwgev'},{$set:{userId:'czd8283j8hr7h4z8y'},{multi:true}})

E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:91
```

Comment: Try this `db.safetyHistoryCol.update({userId:'iu8fjfuyjd0jjwgev'},{$set:{userId:'czd8283j8hr7h4z8y'}},{multi:true})`

Comment: @Veeram oops.. bad syntax closing "}"

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way `db.safetyHistoryCol.updateMany({},{userId:'iu8fjfuyjd0jjwgev'},{$set:{userId:'czd8283j8hr7h4z8y'},{multi:true}})`